# Mesh deformer objects work on viewport but not in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers, 3d-view, displacement, surface-deform

I'm working on a fish project, and I want to pose the fin of my fish. The fin is composed of two objects. And I want to deform them together.

So I add a mesh deformer modifier on the fins.

[image]

The target object of the mesh deformer modifier has a displace modifier, so I can deform the fins.

[image]

As you can see, it works on the viewport.

[image: viewport]
[image: viewport rendered]

But on the final render, it doesn't work.

[image: render]

Any solution for this issue? Do I need to apply the displace modifier?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I don't know if that's the problem but you've got one more subdiv level in render mode than in viewport mode in the subdivision modifier

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the same value for levels viewport and render, in the *Subdivision* modifier.